# Firebird: Как сделать запрос sql на изменение в связанной таблице

Tags: sql, firebird

У меня есть таблицы `PAYMENT` и `GENAGENT`. В таблице `PAYMENT` находится ссылка на таблицу `GENAGENT` имя поля - `REF_GENAGENT`.

Я хочу изменить значение поле `NAME` таблицы `GENAGENT`. Но получаю ошибку:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 2, column 1 INNER (SQL: `UPDATE PAYMENT INNER JOIN GENAGENT on PAYMENT.REF_GENAGENT = GENAGENT.GENAGENT_ID set GENAGENT.NAME = 'SSS' where REF_GENAGENT=3` )

мой запрос:

```php
$pay = DB::select("UPDATE PAYMENT 
                   JOIN GENAGENT on PAYMENT.REF_GENAGENT = GENAGENT.GENAGENT_ID
                   set GENAGENT.NAME = 'SSS' where REF_GENAGENT = 3");
```

Использую БД firebird.

Comment: `UPDATE GENAGENT set GENAGENT.NAME = 'SSS' where GENAGENT.GENAGENT_ID=3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В СУБД Firebird, как собственно и в стандарте SQL конструкция UPDATE может быть выполнена только над одной таблицей, а не соединением или объединением.

Maestro в комментариях вам ответил.

```
UPDATE GENAGENT set NAME = 'SSS' where GENAGENT_ID=3
```

Если вам нужно выполнить действие только в том случае, если есть запись в `PAYMENT` (inner join отсечёт записи без связи), то можно выполнить ещё и дополнительную проверку существования:

```
UPDATE GENAGENT G set NAME = 'SSS'
WHERE G.GENAGENT_ID=3
  AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PAYMENT P WHERE P.REF_GENAGENT = G.GENAGENT_ID)
```

Также ваш запрос можно перевести на синтаксис firebird через подзапрос:

```
UPDATE GENAGENT G SET NAME = 'SSS'
WHERE G.GENAGENT_ID IN (SELECT P.REF_GENAGENT FROM PAYMENT P WHERE P.REF_GENAGENT = 3)
```

Если ваша тройка была выбрана в интерфейсе из таблицы PAYMENT, то выражение в скобках может дать только одно значение 3, и заменив `IN (…)` на `= 3` мы и получим первый ответ.

Если же тройка может и отсутствовать в таблице PAYMENT, но есть индекс по полю REF_GENAGENT, то оптимизатор заменит запрос с `IN` на запрос с `EXISTS`, который я привёл вторым.